# error al pasar datos de gridview a otro webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

estoy tratando de cuando le de click a seleccionar en el gridview me lo muestre en otro webform para luego crear un ticket y almacenarlo en una base de datos, el gridview se llena a través de un archivo txt pero cuando quiero pasar los datos que seleccione me arroja un error cs0246 creo que no me reconoce el método publico que declare no lo reconoce el código donde creo el método y el evento click del gridview.

```
public class datos
{
    public string fecha { get; set; }
    public string nPlanta { get; set; }
    public string mezcla { get; set; }
    public string horaIni { get; set; }
    public string horaFin { get; set; }
    public string peso { get; set; }
}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

     datos obj = new datos()
    {
        fecha = row.Cells[0].Text,
        nPlanta = row.Cells[1].Text,
        mezcla = row.Cells[2].Text,
        horaIni = row.Cells[3].Text,
        horaFin = row.Cells[4].Text,
        peso = row.Cells[5].Text
    };

    Session["DataMiClase"] = obj;

    Response.Redirect("ticket.aspx");
}
```

Este el código donde esos datos que seleccione me deben aparecer

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      datos obj = (datos)Session["DataMiClase"];

        if (obj != null)
        {
            lbl1.Text = obj.fecha;
            lbl2.Text = obj.nPlanta;
            lbl3.Text = obj.mezcla;
            lbl4.Text = obj.horaIni;
            lbl5.Text = obj.horaFin;
            lbl6.Text = obj.peso;

        }
    }
}
```

Texto del error:

> Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'datos' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) produccion  C:\Users\jose f leon c\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\produccion\ticket.aspx.cs  16

Comment: Si no te importa, peganos exactamente todo el error. Es posible que sea la clase `datos` la que no reconoce, tendrás que poner un `using`

Comment: si el error me lo tira es en la clase datos en el webform2

Comment: Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'datos' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) produccion C:\Users\jose f leon c\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\produccion\ticket.aspx.cs 16 Active
este es el error que me arroja en el webform2

Comment: Pues eso, tendrás que añadir un `using`. si te pones encima de `(datos)` donde te da el error, te sale una especie de desplegable para que te meta el using necesario automaticamente

Comment: yo pensaba lo mismo pero no me da la opción de colocar el using

Comment: Estan ambas clases en el mismo projecto? Si no es así, tendras que importar el proyecto en el que está la definicion de `datos`

Comment: si están ambas en el mismo proyecto

Comment: espera.. algo no me gusta.. donde esta definida la clase datos?

Comment: la clase datos esta definida en mi webform1 donde de alli me traigo los datos y mostrarlos en el webform2 que es donde me marca el error

Comment: ¿Error de compilación o de ejecución?, a primera vista la clase `datos` está contenida en la clase del 1er. formulario, lo cual no es visible para el ámbito del 2do. formulario. Podrías agregar la clase a un archivo `*.cs` y que esté contenida en el `App_Code`.

Comment: @Pikoh no encuentro la razón de realizar un `using` si no veo que la clase tenga recursos administrados.

Comment: @Davlio es lo mismo usar `using webform1;` que `webform1.datos` como pones en tu respuesta: la cosa es que debes indicar en que clase está la clase que quieres utilizar. Yo creo que hay algo en la estructura del proyecto de OP que no es correcto, sin verlo es complicado dar una respuesta

Comment: muchas gracias a todos ya pude solucionar el error que tenia gracias a @Pikoh el error lo tenia con visual studio que no me quería el webform dentro del proyecto por eso no podía leer la clase

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo en el código y en los comentarios, tienes un problema de compilación por el ámbito a la clase `datos` desde el segundo formulario.

Solo sería necesario:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack) return;

    datos obj = Session["DataMiClase"] as webform1.datos;

    if (obj != null)
    {
        lbl1.Text = obj.fecha;
        lbl2.Text = obj.nPlanta;
        lbl3.Text = obj.mezcla;
        lbl4.Text = obj.horaIni;
        lbl5.Text = obj.horaFin;
        lbl6.Text = obj.peso;
    }    
}
```

Donde, `webform1` es clase del primer formulario que contiene la clase `datos`.

---

*Como recomendación te sugiero que utilices una mejor [notación](http://blog.unreal4u.com/2011/03/sobre-convenciones-y-notaciones-hungara-camelcase-etc/), en mi humilde opinión uso CamelCase.*